# Why failing to adjust display's resolution in Debian 8.5 of Skylake CPU?

Tags: debian, system-installation, resolution, display-settings, skylake

Fig. 1 My current display's resolution    1024x768 and I cannot change it in Settings, Fig. 2 Output example

[image]
[image]

My screen resolution is max 1920x1080.
I do

```
# http://superuser.com/a/716837/2005
root@masi:/home/masi# cvt 1920 1080
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

# Same output if without `su` here
root@masi:/home/masi# xrandr --newmode "1920x1080" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  19
```

Proposals

- `su` is not needed in some stage (example [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/441075/25388) about *Failed to get size of gamma for output default when trying to add new screen resolution*). I run the first command without `su` but the same failure output.
- ...

Differential conditions

- Bad skylake 6th generation Inter CPU support in the Linux kernel of Debian 8.5, which is complicating the graphics, the extension of the thread [How Smooth is Upgrading Linux kernel in Debian 8.5?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307210/how-smooth-is-upgrading-linux-kernel-in-debian-8-5).
- ...

Later steps will fail `xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1920x1080"` and `xrandr --output VGA1 --mode "1920x1080"`.

Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
OS: Debian 8.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to Linux kernel 4.6 with backports which has sufficient Skylake support, as described in the thread [How Smooth is Upgrading Linux kernel in Debian 8.5?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/307210/16920). Run in 3.16.x kernel mode as `su`, `apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel`, which solves the bugs at the startup then with the new kernel, putting your system use another graphics package, most like `modesetting`. Output: 1920x1080 resolution.