# How Smooth is Upgrading Linux kernel in Debian 8.5?

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, system-installation, upgrade, skylake

I would like to upgrade my Linux kernel to 4.7 in Debian 8.5, since it has significant better Skylake 6th generation support than the current linux kernel. In Ubuntu 16.04, the upgrade is easy. However, I now need Debian 8.5 because of stability, and I would like to do the same upgrade for it.

### Testing StephenKitt's answer

I upgrade the kernel and reboot, but I get unsuccessfully when loading the OS. 
Fig. 1 Failure messages in startup

[image]

### 2nd iteration - Solving the Bug in startup [GAD3R]

1. Boot in Linux kernel 3.16.x
2. Run as `su`, `apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel`
3. Reboot

Output: works! Resolution is now the 1920x1080. Since there is no complete support of Skylake in Linux kernel 4.6 etc this artifact [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/307426/16920) in Matlab 2016a without a firmware, you need some non-free adjustments as firmware; which you maybe already free firmware in Linux kernel 4.7

```
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/307435/16920
apt-get -t jessie-backports install firmware-misc-nonfree
```

### `xserver-xorg-video-intel` abnormal installation and its action's prevention

I find out that the package `xserver-xorg-video-intel` may get installed as a dependency (and all its dependencies) in other conditions, as described a case in the thread [How to Recover Debian of LK backports where runlevel conflict?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/308709/16920) 
The idea is to prevent the action of the package although it get installed by creating the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

```
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/308709/16920
Section "Device"
        Identifier "Intel"
        Driver "modesetting"
EndSection

## Bugs 
# 1. LK 3.16 will fail now but LK 4.6 will work. TODO in the thread https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/308709/16920
```

Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
OS: Debian 8.5
Related: [Asus Zenbook UX303UA Linux compatibility](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/4g2w35/asus_zenbook_ux303ua_linux_compatibility/), [Linux Kernel - Mobile Skylake 6th Generation - Power Management](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/4fruyd/linux_kernel_mobile_skylake_6th_generation_power/)

Comment: Boot the `3.16` kernel , remove `xserver-xorg-video-intel` then reboot into the `4.6` kernel

Comment: @GAD3R Works! When can I install back the package?

Comment: You need to install the intel graphic card from backport

Comment: Actually you don't, Intel GPUs no longer need a separate driver on Linux. See the last paragraph in the [package description](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/xserver-xorg-video-intel): "The use of this driver is discouraged if your hw is new enough (ca. 2007 and newer). You can try uninstalling this driver and let the server use it's builtin modesetting driver instead."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to install a newer kernel is to use [Jessie backports](https://backports.debian.org/).

First you need to add Jessie backports to your repositories, if it's not already there:

```
echo deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
```

(as root), then

```
apt-get update
apt-get -t jessie-backports install linux-image-amd64
```

will install the current default [backported kernel](https://packages.debian.org/source/jessie-backports/linux) (4.8 as of this writing).

To provide the appropriate firmware for your laptop's wi-fi, you need to add `non-free` and install `firmware-iwlwifi`:

```
echo deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
apt-get update
apt-get -t jessie-backports install firmware-iwlwifi
```

To solve the display problems, you can remove [`xserver-xorg-video-intel`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/xserver-xorg-video-intel) (nowadays Intel GPUs don't need a separate driver, they can use the kernel's mode-setting support), as suggested by [GAD3R](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/153195/gad3r):

```
apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

(You may need to install `xserver-xorg-video-dummy` to satisfy other packages' dependencies.)

You should also install the Skylake firmware to enable all the GPU features:

```
apt-get -t jessie-backports install firmware-misc-nonfree
```

Enabling backports is safe: newer packages are not picked up automatically from backports, you need to explicitly select them using `-t jessie-backports` as above (but once you've done that, updates to the upgraded packages are picked up by `apt-get upgrade`).

Version 4.6 of the kernel already provided good support for Skylake, and it's improved since. If you upgrade as above, running `apt-get upgrade` will automatically upgrade to later versions of the kernel once they become available in the backports.

Comment: @StephenKitt the needed driver is `xserver-xorg-video-intel` https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/xserver-xorg-video-intel

Comment: @GAD3R read the last paragraph of the package description in the link you gave above ;-).

Comment: @Masi the kernel packages will tell you about potentially missing firmware whenever they're installed or upgraded. For a complete answer I suggest you post that as a separate question.

Comment: Please, consider to add this fix here http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/308709/16920 in your answer because there is some things which cause `xserver-xorg-video-intel` be installed as a dependency back to the system, thus conflicting the system configuration. The fix will prevent the action of `xserver-xorg-video-intel` and we are monitoring how stable it can be now. - - Please, provide also your opinion and/or feedback about it.

Comment: Please, see the thread about system failures with external displays when using this configuration http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/320993/16920 I am troubleshooting now.

Answer (score 2):

You can compile the latest stable kernel version `4.7.2` from the official [website](https://www.kernel.org/) , following the steps described [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-building-installing-a-custom-linux-kernel/)

1. `su`
2. `apt-get install git fakeroot build-essential ncurses-dev xz-utils libssl-dev bc`
3. `apt-get install kernel-package`
4. `cd /tmp/`
5. `wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.7.2.tar.xz`
6. `unxz linux-4.7.2.tar.xz`

   `tar xvf linux-4.7.tar`
7. `cd linux-4.7`
8. `cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config`
9. `make menuconfig`
10. `make-kpkg clean`
11. `fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --revision=1.0.NAS kernel_image kernel_headers -j 16`
12. `ls  ../*.deb`
13. `dpkg -i *.deb`
14. `reboot`

Answer (score 1):

My OS is **Debian Jessie** with **Mate** desktop

```
root@s32408:~# uname -a
Linux s32408 4.8.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.8.15-2~bpo8+2 (2017-01-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

After upgrading the kernel to 4.8 from backports to fix a WIFI issue, I encountered the display bug when rebooting the system. Then I removed the Intel driver as stated above and it fixed the bug.

But, doing so, many essential packages became "no longer required". I did not pay attention in the first place and did some cleaning afterwards:

```
apt-get autoremove
```

And after the next reboot, **I lost my graphical desktop and many useful applications**.

---

Then I reinstalled a brand new OS and I found that installing the updated Intel driver from backports (instead of removing it) also fixes the display bug but does not break dependencies. In other words I did :

```
apt-get -t jessie-backports install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

instead of:

```
apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

You may prefer to remove the driver anyway and tamper with dependencies to overcome the breakage as suggested by StephenKitt in the comments. Up to you.

Note that **XCFE** desktop is also affected by this issue but **Gnome** desktop is not.

Thanks to Léo Léopold Hertz for the hint about Gnome and StephenKitt for his great patience ;)

Comment: I did not find any complications in the same procedure with Gnome. I think your case can be Mate specific.

Comment: You could also install `xserver-xorg-video-dummy` to satisfy the dependencies instead.

Comment: @Stephen Thanks, I tried this but it didn't work... Still got the display bug with it.

Comment: I don't understand — you say "I removed the Intel driver and it worked", and "installing the updated Intel driver from backports would also fix the display bug"; what setup gives the display bug? Installing the `dummy` package only satisfies the dependencies, the X server won't use it.

Comment: @StephenKitt Just before the statement "To avoid this", note that I had reinstalled a new OS from scratch (I will update this). You need to understand that in my current setup/situation I've got two options to fix the display bug:
- either I remove the Intel driver but it breaks dependencies
- or I install the newest driver from backports which breaks nothing at all

Installing 'dummy' isn't an option since it does not fix the display issue.

Comment: Installing `dummy` goes with removing the Intel driver; it fixes the dependency breakage, but you do need to do both.

Comment: @StephenKitt My explanation wasn't accurate. If I remove the Intel driver, the dependencies get broken and there is no way back. Installing `dummy` doesn't fix them. And even if I install the Intel driver back, the dependencies remain broken... Then I have to reinstall the OS from scratch. There might be something obvious that I'm missing but like I said I'm a beginner ;)

Comment: OK, that means that removing the Intel driver is removing other packages (simultaneously), and you'd need to restore these to fix things. (`apt-get` & co. would tell you what's going to happen before they actually remove the packages though.) If you install the `dummy` driver at the same time as you remove the Intel driver (or before), you won't run into this issue.

Comment: @StephenKitt Yes `apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel` warns me about the dependencies about to be broken in the first place. And I just realized that fixing the dependencies is just as simple as `apt-get install X` where X is everything that was marked as "no longer required". But maybe this method is not really clean ? I think I'll start from scratch again and test the `dummy` install before the driver removal. I'll let you know if I do so. Thank you.

Comment: @StephenKitt OK so as stated above I reinstalled a fresh OS with Mate. This time I tried to install `dummy` before removing the Intel driver, but the result is the same. If I do, many mandatory packages will be marked as "no longer required"... Now I intend to try again with the Gnome desktop. I'll let you know if that changes anything.

Comment: `apt-get remove` doesn't mark packages as "no longer required", it *removes* packages which depend on whatever it is you're removing (`xserver-org-video-intel` here). Those removals cause other packages to be "no longer required", but that comes after you've confirmed the actual removals. Could you paste the output of `apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel` somewhere? (Cancel the removal afterwards...)

Comment: @StephenKitt Understood, my wording was inadequate.  
`me@s32408:~$ sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  alsa-base dmz-cursor-theme dns-root-data dnsmasq-base enchant eom eom-common
  espeak-data ffmpegthumbnailer galculator geoclue-2.0 gimp gimp-data
  gir1.2-atk-1.0 gir1.2-atspi-2.0 gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0
  gir1.2-gtk-2.0 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-mate-panel gir1.2-pango-1.0
...`

Comment: ... output skipped ...    
  `qdbus qt-at-spi qtchooser qtcore4-l10n sound-theme-freedesktop speech-dispatcher speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins sudo udisks upower
  usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data x11-apps x11-session-utils xbrlapi xinit xorg zenity zenity-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  task-desktop task-mate-desktop xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-intel
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 2,730 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]`

Comment: @StephenKitt Btw I noticed that installing `dummy` indeed helps a bit by decreasing the enormous list of packages that would become "no longer required". For instance this concerns several `xserver-xorg-*` packages.

Comment: Thanks for the info; the issue is that `task-desktop` depends on *all* the video drivers :-(. (The important information here isn't the "no longer required" stuff at the start, but "The following packages will be REMOVED" at the end.) To remove the Intel driver without breaking everything, you need to explicitly install `lightdm`, `mate-desktop-environment`, and `xorg` as well as the `dummy` driver.

Comment: @StephenKitt Your suggestion decreases the (still big) list of "no longer required" packages but the list of "will be REMOVED" packages remains the same. Well... I don't want to bother you too much with this... :-/

Comment: I've just tried with Gnome. When I remove the Intel driver, the list of "no longer required" packages is quite short and the list of "will be REMOVED" packages is the same as with Mate. After the first reboot the desktop still works fine (just like with Mate). Then if I issue `apt-get autoremove` and reboot, the desktop keeps on working fine unlike Mate. So indeed, my problem is Mate-related. Moreover it affects XCFE too (I tried).