# How to Calibrate Caret-Cursor's position when unstable Cursor in Debian?

Tags: debian, cursor, caret-cursor

Condition: unstable caret-cursor and its position
Other complications: many enter-artifacts, much lost content because sudden selections of contents and overwrites, often <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> does not work etc in *Google Product Forums* so much lost work time; my typing speed in Debian now: 10-30 WPM; normally, 80-95 WPM long-term with Dvorak

- configurating *Keyboard > Typing* in Fig. 1 cannot solve the artifacts so there must be something internal going on; possible related to, touchpad/...
- keybooard-layout independent - occurs in Qwerty and Dvorak
- no firmware errors - `dmesg |grep firmware` returns no relevant errors/warnings
- keyboard-independent - problems occur with an external keyboard too

I had to do about two corrections every sentence because of abnormal typing configuration. I think I am not touching the touchpad neither by accident. I think I have much more typing artifacts now than with Ubuntu 16.04.

Fig. 1 Options which I change to find optimal configuration but not sufficient and  something internal must be going on

[image]

System characteristics

1. I purged already `xserver-xorg-video-intel` because many bugs so using `modesetting` and (2)
2. Backported Linux kernel (4.6) and Skylake CPU support and firmware installed (thread [How Smooth is Upgrading Linux kernel in Debian 8.5?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/307210/16920))

   - `apt-get -t jessie-backports install linux-image-amd64`
   - `apt-get -t jessie-backports install firmware-misc-nonfree`
3. Installed wifi firmware

   - `apt-get -t jessie-backports install firmware-iwlwifi`

Proposals

1. Some missing firmware because no firmware errors, severe problem and the setting *Keyboard > Typing*
2. Insufficient Skylake support in Linux kernel 4.6? I will exclude this thing  by trying 4.7. - - I think CPU graphic can affect cursor's location, which stability seems to be the main problem here.

Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
Debian: 8.5 64 bit
Linux kernel: 4.6 backported
Keyboard layout: Qwerty, Dvorak, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fig. 1 Disable touchpad while typing, Fig. 2 *Keyboard > Typing* settings, Fig. 3 Disable long-key presses, Fig. 4 Better long-term WPM by using Fig. 3's option

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I think the problem is mainly caused by the over-sensitive touchpad, which causes the cursor's position change much. I did the following change i.e. disable touchpad, while typing, and it resolves the problem significantly in Fig. 1. 
Then, there is the problem of having long-presses by accident when typing fast, so I think disabling *Key presses repeat when key is held down* is the best option here in Fig. 3, but Fig. 2 is also optional but there you should be able to calibrate long-presses individually, which is not possible by defaults, extended in the thread [How to Have key-repeats of Arrow keys when disabled key-repeats?](http://How%20to%20Have%20key-repeats%20of%20Arrow%20keys%20when%20disabled%20key-repeats?) for arrow-keys.

### How to Calibrate your Typing Speed?

I play play.typeracer.com, where I found one good condition with the settings in Fig. 2, but later I find Fig. 3's option better because long-presses cause much problems etc when making typing mistakes. 
I can reach about 10% greater WPM by disabling long-presses in Fig. 4. 
Other changes needed in my tying

- Use to alleviate no-long-presses for removing a word and undoing, respectively, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd>/<kbd>z</kbd>.
- Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>arrow key</kbd> in moving. It would be great to still have long-presses of arrow-keys although you have disabled the main option, because it is the mainly feature needed for repositioning the caret position, extended in the thread [How to Have key-repeats of Arrow keys when disabled key-repeats?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/307614/16920)

Differential solutions

1. Is there a way to have it so that key repeats aren't disabled but only start after you've held a key down for a longer time? ([Random832](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/307614/16920))

Conclusion

- I still get some center-artifacts and unstable cursor position about 1/40 of times, so significantly less than two times per sentence. So it is likely that the cause of the bug/issue is still existing in the system.