# How to find missing firmwares in Zenbook?

Tags: debian, system-installation, firmware, zenbook

This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/307211/16920) motivates me to find missing firmwares in my ultrabook, because I am experiencing difficult typing with many artifacts ([here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/307329/16920) about unable to calibrate typing speed) and CPU up-downs now in one-day old Debian 8.5 with Dvorak. 
Stephen says that the kernel packages can tell you about missing firmware whenever they are installed or upgraded. However, I would like to get more complete review on it. 
Characteristics

- Graphics

  ```
  lspci -nnk | egrep -iA3 "VGA"
  00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1916] (rev 07)
  Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:247a]
  ```

  Kernel driver in use: i915
      00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1903] (rev 08)
- About failed firmwares where `iwlwifi` are old messages, I think

  ```
  masi@masi:~$ dmesg | grep firmware
  [    1.878929] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-21.ucode (-2)
  [    1.878967] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-21.ucode failed with error -2
  [    1.878985] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-20.ucode (-2)
  [    1.879016] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-20.ucode failed with error -2
  [    1.879027] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode (-2)
  [    1.879060] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode failed with error -2
  [    1.879070] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode (-2)
  [    1.879101] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode failed with error -2
  [    1.879111] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode (-2)
  [    1.879142] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode failed with error -2
  [    1.883577] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-16.ucode
  [    1.883896] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
  [    1.916244] i915 0000:00:02.0: firmware: failed to load i915/skl_dmc_ver1.bin (-2)
  [    1.916249] i915 0000:00:02.0: Direct firmware load for i915/skl_dmc_ver1.bin failed with error -2
  [    1.916251] i915 0000:00:02.0: Failed to load DMC firmware [https://01.org/linuxgraphics/intel-linux-graphics-firmwares], disabling runtime power management.
  [    2.292574] bluetooth hci0: firmware: direct-loading firmware intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
  [    2.292579] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
  [    2.544000] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
  ```

Installed firmwares and removed packages in debian

- `apt-get -t jessie-backports install linux-image-amd64`
- `apt-get -t jessie-backports install firmware-iwlwifi`
- `apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel`

### 2nd iteration after Stephen's answer

The `non-free` package solves the graphical artifact in Matlab 2016a described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/307426/16920).
My dmesg now where everything is ok [Stephen] because 17-21 of wifi firmware fail, but 16 iteration succeeds eventually; no other firmware failures visible

```
masi@masi:~$ dmesg | grep firmware
[    1.897923] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-21.ucode (-2)
[    1.897961] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-21.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.897973] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-20.ucode (-2)
[    1.898009] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-20.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.898017] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode (-2)
[    1.898121] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.898129] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode (-2)
[    1.898165] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.898173] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode (-2)
[    1.898209] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.904430] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-16.ucode
[    1.904726] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    1.917970] i915 0000:00:02.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1.bin
```

Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
OS: Debian 8.5 64 bit
Linux kernel: 4.6

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci -nnk | egrep -iA3 "VGA"` it will display more info about your graphic card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out firmware your system is looking for but can't find (which is the firmware you might need), you should look for firmware-related messages in your kernel logs:

```
dmesg | grep firmware
```

That will give you the names of firmware files which the kernel is looking for; `apt-file` will then tell you which package to install (if the firmware is packaged).

You've got a Skylake system running with an Intel GPU, you'll probably need at least `firmware-misc-nonfree` (Skylake GPUs need firmware):

```
apt-get -t jessie-backports install firmware-misc-nonfree
```

This will fix the `i915` firmware loading errors. The sequence of `iwlwifi` messages ends with `loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm`, so that's OK; likewise the Bluetooth firmware is loaded successfully too (it's also contained in the `firmware-iwlwifi` package).

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer. With `firmware-misc-nonfree` and `firmware-iwlwifi` you'll have all the firmware your system needs.

Comment: `I915/skl_dmc_ver1.bin` is firmware that's used by the Skylake GPU, so it makes sense that it would fix the graphical artifacts.

Comment: That looks fine; `iwlwifi` tries to load various versions of the firmware (notice the decreasing number at the end, from 21 to 17) and eventually succeeds in loading version 16.

Comment: As far as firmware goes, I can't think of anything on the Debian side. You might want to check the Asus website to see if there's a BIOS/UEFI update for your system. As far as the typing problems go, update your existing question — it could do with a little more detail ;-).

Comment: I extend the bios update here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/307443/16920 possibly it can solve some problems. What do you think? - - I tried to record you my screen for .gif animation but I get GTK errors/warnings in Kazam, which problem, I extend here http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/307441/16920