# Is this missing dependency-bug of Python3 in Kazam of Debian 8.5?

Tags: debian, software-installation, debugging, python3, zenbook

I tried to record the bug related to my typing but could not get Kazam work as root and as non-root, see following; I installed it by `apt-get install kazam ffmpeg` successfully but not properly because of the errors/warnings

```
root@masi:/home/masi# kazam
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/kazam", line 127, in <module>
    bus = dbus.SessionBus()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/_dbus.py", line 211, in __new__
    mainloop=mainloop)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/_dbus.py", line 100, in __new__
    bus = BusConnection.__new__(subclass, bus_type, mainloop=mainloop)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 122, in __new__
    bus = cls._new_for_bus(address_or_type, mainloop=mainloop)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
root@masi:/home/masi# exit
exit

masi@masi:~$ kazam
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/app.py:145: Warning: value "((GtkIconSize) 32)" of type 'GtkIconSize' is invalid or out of range for property 'icon-size' of type 'GtkIconSize'
  self.builder.add_from_file(os.path.join(prefs.datadir, "ui", "kazam.ui"))

(kazam:5260): Gtk-WARNING **: Symbolic icon kazam-screencast-symbolic of size 24 is in an icon theme directory of size 16

(kazam:5260): Gtk-WARNING **: Symbolic icon kazam-screenshot-symbolic of size 24 is in an icon theme directory of size 16

(kazam:5260): Gtk-WARNING **: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent


(kazam:5260): Gtk-WARNING **: Symbolic icon kazam-fullscreen-symbolic of size 24 is in an icon theme directory of size 16

(kazam:5260): Gtk-WARNING **: Symbolic icon kazam-all-screens-symbolic of size 24 is in an icon theme directory of size 16

(kazam:5260): Gtk-WARNING **: Symbolic icon kazam-window-symbolic of size 24 is in an icon theme directory of size 16

(kazam:5260): Gtk-WARNING **: Symbolic icon kazam-area-symbolic of size 24 is in an icon theme directory of size 16

(kazam:5260): Gtk-WARNING **: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
```

I did as root `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` after that and iterated again but the problem persists.

### Debugging

I run `kazam --debug` and get

```
masi@masi:~$ kazam --debug
DEBUG Kazam - Starting ...
DEBUG Kazam - Running on: debian 8.5
DEBUG Kazam - Kazam version: 1.4.5 NCC-80102
DEBUG Kazam - Starting new instance ...
DEBUG Prefs - XDG_PICTURES is a directory and accessible
DEBUG Prefs-HW - Getting hardware specs
DEBUG Prefs-HW - Getting Video sources.
DEBUG Prefs-HW - Found 1 monitor(s).
DEBUG Prefs-HW -   Monitor 0 - X: 0, Y: 0, W: 1920, H: 1080
DEBUG Main - Gstreamer version detected: 1.4.4.0
DEBUG Main - Setting variables.
DEBUG PulseAudio - Starting mainloop.
DEBUG PulseAudio - Getting API.
DEBUG PulseAudio - Setting context.
DEBUG PulseAudio - Set state callback.
DEBUG PulseAudio - Connecting to server.
DEBUG PulseAudio - Start mainloop.
DEBUG PulseAudio - State connected.
DEBUG Main - Connecting indicator signals.
DEBUG Main - Starting in silent mode: False
DEBUG Indicator - Indicatior silent: False
DEBUG Indicator - Trying to bind hotkeys.
DEBUG Main - Main Window UI setup.
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/app.py:145: Warning: value "((GtkIconSize) 32)" of type 'GtkIconSize' is invalid or out of range for property 'icon-size' of type 'GtkIconSize'
  self.builder.add_from_file(os.path.join(prefs.datadir, "ui", "kazam.ui"))
DEBUG Main - Unable to get name for '<Adjustment object at 0x7f60d8067b88 (GtkAdjustment at 0x1916890)>'

(kazam:3222): Gtk-WARNING **: Symbolic icon kazam-screencast-symbolic of size 24 is in an icon theme directory of size 16

(kazam:3222): Gtk-WARNING **: Symbolic icon kazam-screenshot-symbolic of size 24 is in an icon theme directory of size 16

(kazam:3222): Gtk-WARNING **: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent


(kazam:3222): Gtk-WARNING **: Symbolic icon kazam-fullscreen-symbolic of size 24 is in an icon theme directory of size 16

(kazam:3222): Gtk-WARNING **: Symbolic icon kazam-all-screens-symbolic of size 24 is in an icon theme directory of size 16

(kazam:3222): Gtk-WARNING **: Symbolic icon kazam-window-symbolic of size 24 is in an icon theme directory of size 16

(kazam:3222): Gtk-WARNING **: Symbolic icon kazam-area-symbolic of size 24 is in an icon theme directory of size 16

(kazam:3222): Gtk-WARNING **: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent

DEBUG Prefs - Getting Audio sources.
DEBUG PulseAudio - get_audio_sources() called.
DEBUG PulseAudio - pa_sourcelist_cb()
DEBUG PulseAudio -   IDX: 0
DEBUG PulseAudio -   Name: b'alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor'
DEBUG PulseAudio -   Desc: b'Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo'
DEBUG PulseAudio - pa_sourcelist_cb()
DEBUG PulseAudio -   IDX: 1
DEBUG PulseAudio -   Name: b'alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo'
DEBUG PulseAudio -   Desc: b'Built-in Audio Analog Stereo'
DEBUG PulseAudio - pa_sourcelist_cb() -- finished
DEBUG Prefs -  Device found: 
DEBUG Prefs -   - 0
DEBUG Prefs -   - alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor
DEBUG Prefs -   - Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
DEBUG Prefs -  Device found: 
DEBUG Prefs -   - 1
DEBUG Prefs -   - alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
DEBUG Prefs -   - Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
DEBUG Main - Capture cursor: True.
DEBUG Main - Capture cursor_pic: True.
DEBUG Main - Capture borders_pic: True.
```

### Testing GAD3R's proposal

I run `apt-get build-dep kazam` successfully, then again `kazam` but get the similar warnings/errors still

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kazam/app.py:145: Warning: value "((GtkIconSize) 32)" of type 'GtkIconSize' is invalid or out of range for property 'icon-size' of type 'GtkIconSize'
  self.builder.add_from_file(os.path.join(prefs.datadir, "ui", "kazam.ui"))

(kazam:15470): Gtk-WARNING **: Symbolic icon kazam-screencast-symbolic of size 24 is in an icon theme directory of size 16

(kazam:15470): Gtk-WARNING **: Symbolic icon kazam-screenshot-symbolic of size 24 is in an icon theme directory of size 16

(kazam:15470): Gtk-WARNING **: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent


(kazam:15470): Gtk-WARNING **: Symbolic icon kazam-fullscreen-symbolic of size 24 is in an icon theme directory of size 16

(kazam:15470): Gtk-WARNING **: Symbolic icon kazam-all-screens-symbolic of size 24 is in an icon theme directory of size 16

(kazam:15470): Gtk-WARNING **: Symbolic icon kazam-window-symbolic of size 24 is in an icon theme directory of size 16

(kazam:15470): Gtk-WARNING **: Symbolic icon kazam-area-symbolic of size 24 is in an icon theme directory of size 16

(kazam:15470): Gtk-WARNING **: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
```

I think this may be the problem that Kazam wants python3 but I have python 2.7.9 (`python --version` gives `Python 2.7.9`), so there can be a missing dependency. How to proceed?

Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
OS: Debian 8.5
Linux kernel: 4.6 (backports' one)
Graphics: `modesetting` and `non-free` package for skylake CPU support
Case in Kazam suppot: https://answers.launchpad.net/kazam/+question/378875

Comment: Run `apt-get build-dep kazam`

Comment: @GAD3R Please, see the body. It does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maintainer contacted but no resolution and/or answer.