# How to Update Bios in Debian of Zenbook?

Tags: upgrade, bios, zenbook

Situation: I have only Debian 8.5 in my system without Windows 10, and I would like to update the Bios of Zenbook UX303UA R4028T
Options

1. Update bios with Debian i.e. do the flashing somehow, since no code exists for it.
2. Install Windows-10 alongside the Debian installation, and update the bios with Windows 10 with the official software.

### Solving the thing with official Asus chat

They point me to the thread [here](http://www.asus.com/support/faq/1008276/) where you see that you need the flash utility to the update on Windows.
However, I am still unsure how to replace it for Debian or if you can do the update directly in Bios. 
So there are only updates in Windows 10 section of the manufacturer [here](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks/ASUS-ZenBook-UX303UA/HelpDesk_Download/).

1. BIOS 208

   ```
   Description BIOS 208
   Update FW
   File Size   2.48 MBytesupdate 2016/05/05
   ```
2. Windows BIOS Flash Utility

   - not sure what to do with this - - TODO?

     ```
     BIOS-Utilities (1)

     Version V3.0.1

     Description Windows BIOS Flash Utility
     File Size   888.63 KBytes 2015/08/14 update
     ```

### After Stephen's answer

Final result: Bios was the latest (updated already on April 2016 to 208) which I saw in Easy Boot [Stephen], so I did not need to update. I just wonder why Asus support did not have proper knowledge of Bios update in Linux, and about Bios states in different systems when serial is known.

Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA R4028T
OS: Debian 8.5 64 bit
Linux kernel: 4.6
Keywords: `bios firmware upgrade asus ux303ua R4028T download`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the firmware from the built-in firmware setup; this is [documented on the Asus site](http://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1008859).