# Missing firmware in Debian?

Tags: drivers, system-installation, firmware

**Initial Problem**

Firstly, I think I should note that I have a Skylake CPU, as I have heard there are issues with Skylake CPUs and this i915 driver from [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics#Troubleshooting). I don't really understand enough about linux to feel comfortable doing the things they mention however. So I would appreciate anyone to explain what I would be doing as much as possible. I also updated to Stretch, as I had heard that they had better support for the Skylake. So that is the current version I am on.

My issue stems from a slow startup which I noticed after I repartitioned my `/` to make it larger. I did this by removing swap, which was between my `/` and `/home`, and then I extended `/` into the beginning of `/home`, and then cut the end of `/home` to recreate `swap`. I've already fixed all the UUID stuff. All of this using a Gparted live CD.

I think that the issue is stemming from something in the kernel, as

`systemd-analyze: Startup finished in 16.130s (firmware) + 2.525s (loader) + 33.178s (kernel) + 10.969s (userspace) = 1min 2.804s` so there appears to be some issue with the kernel loading properly.

Also, `dmesg` returns the following segment (I cut it out because it is the part that contains errors). So it looks like there is a missing i915 driver perhaps? I am unsure where to look for that.

```
[   33.513592] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[   33.513593] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
[   33.513594] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain uncore
[   33.513595] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain dram
[   33.517028] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
[   33.517550] i915 0000:00:02.0: firmware: failed to load i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin (-2)
[   33.517553] i915 0000:00:02.0: Direct firmware load for i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin failed with error -2
[   33.517554] i915 0000:00:02.0: Failed to load DMC firmware [https://01.org/linuxgraphics/intel-linux-graphics-firmwares], disabling runtime power management.
[   33.529588] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
[   33.532829] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[   33.532888] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input13
[   33.532950] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20160711 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[   33.559664] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[   33.559932] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   33.581390] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC892: line_outs=3 (0x14/0x15/0x16/0x0/0x0) type:line
[   33.581390] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   33.581391] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   33.581391] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   33.581392] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    dig-out=0x11/0x1e
[   33.581392] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[   33.581393] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Front Mic=0x19
[   33.581393] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Rear Mic=0x18
[   33.581393] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Line=0x1a
[   33.599112] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input14
[   33.599153] input: HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input15
[   33.599184] input: HDA Intel PCH Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input16
[   33.599209] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Front as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input17
[   33.599234] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out Surround as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input18
[   33.599258] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out CLFE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input19
[   33.599285] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input20
[   33.599312] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input21
[   33.599342] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input22
[   34.278927] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[   34.320637] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[   34.362341] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[   34.404044] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[   34.445749] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[   34.487451] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[   34.529151] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[   34.529601] [drm:intel_dp_start_link_train [i915]] *ERROR* failed to train DP, aborting
[   34.573582] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[   34.592652] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[   34.686901] EXT4-fs (sda4): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   34.861106] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   34.879100] [drm] RC6 on
[   35.443123] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   35.662991] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   38.593098] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[   38.593160] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[ 6351.566645] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[ 6351.608392] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[ 6351.650141] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[ 6351.691875] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[ 6351.733621] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[ 6351.775352] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[ 6351.817087] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[ 6351.817536] [drm:intel_dp_start_link_train [i915]] *ERROR* failed to train DP, aborting
[ 6351.884729] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[ 6351.926468] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[ 6351.968201] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[ 6352.009936] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[ 6352.051673] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[ 6352.093401] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[ 6352.135129] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[ 6352.135577] [drm:intel_dp_start_link_train [i915]] *ERROR* failed to train DP, aborting
[ 6352.151887] [drm:gen8_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* CPU pipe B FIFO underrun
```

I think this issue may be the reason my MATLAB has visual tearing, as it is mentioned in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307425/how-to-find-missing-firmwares-in-zenbook). Do I just need to `sudo apt-get install firmware-misc-nonfree`? I have had graphical tearing in MATLAB for as long as I can remember, but only now after I have repartitioned `/` do I see this boot issue.

**Update**

I installed the firmware package. The restart went smooth, and much more quickly:

`systemd-analyze : Startup finished in 16.340s (firmware) + 2.347s (loader) + 2.406s (kernel) + 10.739s (userspace) = 31.834s`

And in `dmesg`, the firmware seems to load, displaying:

```
[    2.936930] i915 0000:00:02.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin
[    2.937267] [drm] Finished loading i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin (v1.26)
```

However, I still have this error from before:

```
[    3.683213] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[    3.725006] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[    3.766802] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[    3.808607] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[    3.850408] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[    3.892210] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[    3.933994] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915]] *ERROR* too many full retries, give up
[    3.934444] [drm:intel_dp_start_link_train [i915]] *ERROR* failed to train DP, aborting
```

How can I go about troubleshooting this?

Comment: The suggested duplicate doesn’t address your partitioning change, but it should help with the firmware issue. The boot delay might be caused by your system waiting for a partition it no longer has (or whose name changed).

Comment: The system appears to be booting as fast as it did before, not sure if the added firmware helped or not. And while I don't get one of the errors I did before, I still get one of them.

Comment: @StephenKitt Can you explain why this is a duplicate, and what it might have to do with X.org? To me this looks like something to do with the i915 driver. I don't really understand the answer given on the other question, and my kernel version is 4.8.0.1; I am currently using Stretch because I thought it would have better support for my CPU.

Comment: OK, I tend to assume that “Debian” is Debian 8 here; the suggested duplicate explains how to install a newer kernel and firmware from backports. Since you’re running Debian 9 you already have those (well, nearly, the current kernel is 4.9 in Debian 9), so the other answer isn’t relevant. The DP training error might be a kernel problem, so give 4.9 a shot...