# How to Improve Power Management in Zenbook UX303UA?

Tags: debian, power-management, zenbook

Situation: to improve the power management of the zenbook when I need computation power, especially when the zenbook is in AC
I am experimenting about 3 hour battery life without any computation, without any firmware failures/issues and just typing in Stackexchange network in my new UX303UA. 
Expected battery time is up to 7 hours, [here](https://www.asus.com/us/Notebooks/ASUS-ZenBook-UX303UA/) its Asus website.
Arch Linux wiki confirms in the same series ultrabook

> Battery has a design capacity of 4429mAh, and is able to provide just over 3 hours of autonomy under normal circumstances (average load of around 0.3 and WiFi enabled, brightness lowered to mid-range) without serious power saving tweaks. - - ACPI tools are able to correctly detect the battery state.

They recommend [Laptop mode tools](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Laptop_Mode_Tools), which I will be testing

1. `apt-get install laptop-mode-tools`
2. Enable `laptop-mode.service`, where the following command should return `2`

   ```
   cat /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode
   ```
3. Actually, I do not understand why they propose to change to the laptop mode to `1` where I would like to keep `0` when in AC because I need power in computations

   ```
   # http://askubuntu.com/questions/180712/how-to-enable-laptop-mode
   # edit /etc/laptop-mode/laptop-mode.conf`       
   ENABLE_LAPTOP_MODE_ON_AC=1 
   # where I want to have zero. Why they propose 1?
   ```
4. Restart `laptop-mode` as root by `/etc/init.d/laptop-mode restart`

Default power saving states found by `grep` -command

```
root@masi:/home/masi# grep -r '^\(CONTROL\|ENABLE\)_' /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/intel-sata-powermgmt.conf:CONTROL_INTEL_SATA_POWER="auto"
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/radeon-dpm.conf:CONTROL_RADEON_DPM="auto"
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/sched-smt-power-savings.conf:CONTROL_SCHED_SMT_POWER_SAVINGS="auto"
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/start-stop-programs.conf:CONTROL_START_STOP=1
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/wireless-power.conf:CONTROL_WIRELESS_POWER_SAVING="auto"
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/intel_pstate.conf:CONTROL_INTEL_PSTATE="auto"
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/dpms-standby.conf:CONTROL_DPMS_STANDBY="auto"
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/nmi-watchdog.conf:CONTROL_NMI_WATCHDOG="auto"
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/sched-mc-power-savings.conf:CONTROL_SCHED_MC_POWER_SAVINGS="auto"
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/intel-hda-powersave.conf:CONTROL_INTEL_HDA_POWER="auto"
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/pcie-aspm.conf:CONTROL_PCIE_ASPM="auto"
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/auto-hibernate.conf:ENABLE_AUTO_HIBERNATION=0
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/wireless-iwl-power.conf:CONTROL_IWL_POWER="auto"
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/exec-commands.conf:CONTROL_EXEC_COMMANDS="auto"
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/hal-polling.conf:CONTROL_HAL_POLLING="auto"
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/ethernet.conf:CONTROL_ETHERNET="auto"
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/runtime-pm.conf:CONTROL_RUNTIME_AUTOSUSPEND=1
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/configuration-file-control.conf:CONTROL_CONFIG_FILES=0
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/ac97-powersave.conf:CONTROL_AC97_POWER="auto"
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/eee-superhe.conf:CONTROL_SUPERHE="auto"
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/lcd-brightness.conf:CONTROL_BRIGHTNESS=0
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/terminal-blanking.conf:CONTROL_TERMINAL="auto"
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/bluetooth.conf:CONTROL_BLUETOOTH=0
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/cpufreq.conf:CONTROL_CPU_FREQUENCY="auto"
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/cpufreq.conf:CONTROL_CPU_THROTTLING=0
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/wireless-ipw-power.conf:CONTROL_IPW_POWER="auto"
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/video-out.conf:CONTROL_VIDEO_OUTPUTS=0
/etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/battery-level-polling.conf:ENABLE_BATTERY_LEVEL_POLLING=0
```

I am not sure which files are relevant in the power management in the directory `etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/`, etc many authors ignore `ac97-powersave.conf` - - why?

### Iterating GAD3R's answer

Installing the package (`apt-get install laptop-mode-tools`), rebooting and having just the default power options leads to significant increase in battery time. 
The 25% of battery is now about 2h 15 minutes -use so 100% of battery is about 10 hours of use i.e. about 3.5 times more battery time. 
There are only a few options off in the settings' file where I cannot find anything relevant to turn on

```
root@masi:/home/masi# grep =0 /etc/laptop-mode/laptop-mode.conf
#    CONTROL_something=0/1   Determines whether Laptop Mode Tools controls 
VERBOSE_OUTPUT=0
DEBUG=0
ENABLE_LAPTOP_MODE_ON_AC=0
ENABLE_LAPTOP_MODE_WHEN_LID_CLOSED=0
DISABLE_BATTERY_ALARM_CHECK=0
CONTROL_NOATIME=0
CONTROL_HD_WRITECACHE=0
NOLM_BATT_HD_WRITECACHE=0
LM_HD_WRITECACHE=0
```

I do not want to change defaults much. 
Which settings would you change to accomplish the significant improvement in the power management?

Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
OS: Debian 8.5 64 bit
Firmwares: updated and/or installed as described in the thread [How Smooth is Upgrading Linux kernel in Debian 8.5?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/307210/16920)
Linux kernel: 4.6 of backports
Related: [ASUS Zenbook UX303](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ASUS_Zenbook_UX303) in Arch Linux
Other Asus Zenbooks of 2nd gen: [UX301LA](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Asus/UX301LA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To improve Power Management on your Laptop enable all feature of LMT  from `/etc/laptop-mode/laptop-mode.conf` or using the GUI by runing:`gksu lmt-config-gui`

> many authors ignore ac97-powersave.conf - - why?

This feature is useful , only if you have AC97 sound card, you can enable it form `ac97-powersave.conf` file:

```
nano /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/ac97-powersave.conf
```

set the value as bellow :

```
# Control AC97 audio chipset power?
CONTROL_AC97_POWER=1
```

Comment: I think the default configurations are great. They already increased my battery time significantly: 25% of battery corresponds to 2h 15 minutes of use i.e. means about 10 hours battery time with 100% of battery. - - I did not find any option besides the defaults which I would more turn on in the file `/etc/laptop-mode/laptop-mode.conf`. Did you? - - Please, see the body  about parameters which are off by default there.