# Why Mouse Activates 3D Image in non-evaluated NB of Debian Mathematica?

Tags: debian, monitoring, mouse, 3d, mathematica

Condition: controlling 3D Image output of test code by mouse cause all CPUs to 100%; differential solutions do not help; no clicking of mouse on image
Motivation: to understand why mouse activates 3D Image process even when no evaluation of the notebook in Debian Mathematica

Fig. 1 My Desktop where trying to overlay the figure and delete it causes the CPUs to max; doing `Clear[data]` before that does not help

[image]

I need the notebook but the object keeps locking its use. 
Test code

```
(* system info for WRI *)
SystemInformation[]    

(* http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38305/9815 *)
data = Table[
   Exp[-3 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)], {x, -1., 1, .01}, {y, -1., 
    1, .01}, {z, -1., 1, .01}];

Image3D[data, ClipRange -> {{100, 200}, {0, 200}, {100, 200}}, 
 ColorFunction -> Automatic] (* default colour function *)
```

System characteristics

```
masi@masi:~$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.5, 256 bits)
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.3.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
masi@masi:~$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

masi@masi:~$
```

Mathematica startup option as instructed by Wolfram but still unsuccessful output

1. I run

   ```
   masi@masi:~$ rm .Mathematica/ 
   masi@masi:~$ su
   root@masi:/home/masi# rm -r /usr/share/Mathematica/
   ```
2. Do clean start

   ```
   masi@masi:~$ mathematica -cleanstart
   ```
3. Get a new university licence for Mathematica and activate
4. Start mathematica with the option

   ```
   mathematica -mesa
   ```

I contacted Wolfram student support with a link to this thread, waiting their answer for three days.

OS: Debian 8.5
Linux kernel: 4.6 of backports set up as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/307211/16920)
Graphics: modesetting  set up as described in the thread [How Smooth is Upgrading Linux kernel in Debian 8.5?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/307211/16920)
Mathematica: 11 student edition
Mathematica documentation: [How can I address broken 3D graphics on Linux with certain graphics cards](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/23043)
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
Differential solutions: `Clear[data]`, `Quit kernel` in Menu *Evaluation*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Mathematica 11.0.0 in Debian. 
Their testing was mostly in Mint Linux, where they did not obverse the problems. 
I posted a report about the case to Mathematica, where they promptly reacted and fixed the case. 
The new release Mathematica 11.0.1 is significantly better in Debian 8.5.