# No Wlan or Bluetooth Debian 8.7.1 with Intel 8260 card

Tags: debian, bluetooth, iwlwifi

I can't get my WLAN working on a fresh Debian 8.7.1 64bit installation. Maybe you can help me find the issue. The card I am using is an Intel 8260 WLAN/Bluetooth card:

```
# lspci | grep Wire
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
```

I installed iwlwifi with apt and loaded the module:

```
# modprobe -r iwlwifi ; modprobe iwlwifi
```

lsmod output:

```
# lsmod | grep wif
iwlwifi                96547  0
cfg80211              413730  1 iwlwifi
```

iwconfig:

```
# iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

So what am I missing?! I am getting the feel it's because of the firmware not supporting the Kernel?

```
root@dfog:/home/irrgeist# uname -a
Linux debian 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1 (2016-12-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I rebooted the system.

Edit:

```
#ls /lib/firmware/
av7110                iwlwifi-3160-8.ucode     iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode
carl9170-1.fw         iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode     iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode
cis                   iwlwifi-3945-2.ucode     iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode
dsp56k                iwlwifi-4965-2.ucode     iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
hp                    iwlwifi-5000-2.ucode     iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode
intel                 iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode     iwlwifi-8265-22.ucode
isci                  iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode     keyspan_pda
iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode  iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode     RTL8192E
iwlwifi-100-5.ucode   iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode  RTL8192SU
iwlwifi-105-6.ucode   iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode  rtl_nic
iwlwifi-135-6.ucode   iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode  rtlwifi
iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode  iwlwifi-6050-4.ucode     usbduxfast_firmware.bin
iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode  iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode     usbdux_firmware.bin
iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode  iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode     usbduxsigma_firmware.bin
```

sources.list

```
#

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.7.1 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20170116-10:57]/ jessie main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.7.1 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20170116-10:57]/ jessie main

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie main non-free contrib

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [official website](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html) the Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260 work on kernel version `4.1` and higher.

You can add the backports repo to your `sources.list`

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main non-free
```

Update and run `apt-cache search linux-image` to get the available `linux-image` then install a `kernel > 4.1`

e,g :

```
apt-get install linux-image-4.8.0-0.bpo.2-amd64
```

or the latest kernel version:

```
apt-get install linux-image-4.9.0-0.bpo.1-amd64-unsigned
```

Reboot your system and install the [`firmware-iwlwifi`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/firmware-iwlwifi) needed to get the Bluetooth working :

```
apt-get install -t jessie-backports firmware-iwlwifi
```

The wifi firmware `iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode` is included on the `firmware-iwlwifi` package , also it can be added through :

```
wget https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-8000-ucode-16.242414.0.tgz
tar xvf iwlwifi-8000-ucode-16.242414.0.tgz
cd iwlwifi-8000-ucode-16.242414.0
cp iwlwifi* /lib/firmware
```

**EDIT**

To solve the black screen after installing the new kernel reinstall `xserver-xorg-video-intel` from backports , to get more info about the problem , see the answer of [Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/307211/153195).

```
apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel 
apt-get install -t jessie-backports xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Comment: Just did this with ´apt-get install -t jessie-backports linux-image-amd64´ and rebooted...now I get a black screen while booting (it's loading the new Kernel) ... first time I do this kind of task x_X ... switching to TTY works, startx says, it could not find a monitor x_X Guess I have to remove it and do it your way...

Comment: Boot the `3.16` kernel from the advanced option of debian on GRUB menu then install the new kernel using : `apt-get install linux-image-4.9.0-0.bpo.1-amd64-unsigned
`

Comment: Did it, same problem though :(

Comment: run `apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel && apt-get install -t jessie-backports xserver-xorg-video-intel` More info [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/307211/153195)

Comment: just did it, seems to work now :D But didn't remove the old one. Anyway, still no wlan0 available. Did modprobe again and rebooted, nothing.

Comment: Reload the driver `modprobe -r iwlwifi ; modprobe iwlwifi`

Comment: Does not work. I added the files in /lib/firmware to the first post ... maybe it's taking the wrong one?!

Comment: Does the `wireless-tools` is installed on your system?

Comment: yes they are, using iwconfig to check for the interface. ifconfig does list eth0 and lo. same for iwconfig

Comment: I will edit may answer , please add `non-free` to the backports source

Comment: I already did, posted my sources.list in the first post. :/

Comment: Ah now it works, just saw your edit about installing the firmware from the backports...wow! Thank you very much!! :D

Answer (score 2):

according to [intel-supports-site](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html)

you need higher kernel-version (4.1). Try kernel from backports.

Answer (score 1):

I went to the synaptic package manager and typed in iwlwifi, then hit search.
this gave me the option of firmware-iwlwifi, which I selected and installed.
then I rebooted
wifi now seen, I am connected right now.

Debian stretch 9, with the intel 8260 WLAN/Bluetooth card
(I am new to Debian this month but have been using Ubuntu, Mint, Manjaro, since 2012).